# My feature wall does not appear straight in camera

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have created my home as a concept so I can see if I can figure out lighting and other things, but I cannot figure out why this wall appears the way it does.

When i render in Cycles its not straight
[image: Cycles is not straight]
[image: Eevee appears straight]

What setting to fix this?

Comment: Are you trying to use Displacement and Bump?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have enabled real displacement

[image]

but your object only has a few vertices, so the middle is getting bulged.

[image]

Instead, use Bump Only setting, or if you really need displacement you have to have an appropriate amount of geometry and tweak the *Height* setting to taste.